# Proving inequality for integrable function

Tags: calculus, inequality

Given
$$
f(x)=\frac{1-\cos(x)}{x}
$$
I need to prove that
$$
0<\intop_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{4}}f(x)dx\leq\frac{\pi^{2}}{64}
$$

I'm given a hint to use this:
$$
1-\cos(x)\leq\frac{x^{2}}{2}
$$

I used the hint and divided both by $x$ and calculated the integer

$$
\intop_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{4}}\frac{x}{2}dx=\frac{x^{2}}{4}\Big|_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{4}}=\frac{(\frac{\pi}{4})^{2}}{4}=\frac{\pi^{2}}{64}
$$
My problem:
I need to prove the hint but failed, and I failed to prove the left side.

This is what I tried for the left side:
$$
\intop_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{4}}\frac{1-\cos(x)}{x}dx=\intop_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{4}}\frac{1}{x}dx-\intop_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{4}}\frac{\cos(x)}{x}dx=\ln(x)\Big|_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{4}}-...
$$

Comment: The hint is a direct consequence of the Taylor expansion for $\cos x$ at $x=0$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the hint, there are many ways. One possible is to notice that $1-\cos x=2\sin^2(x/2)$ and use the fact that $\sin t\le t$ for $t\ge 0$. Or you can move all the terms to the left (say) and prove that the resulting function is $\le 0$ by showing that it is $=0$ at $x=0$ and has negative derivative for $x>0$.

The left part of the inequality follows from the fact that your function is positive for all $x>0$.

Comment: firsty thank you,i understood the part about the hint,but can you elaborate on the second part? how do i know that? and is it possible to split the integral to 2 parts and somehow do it?

Comment: No. $\cos x\le1$ and therefore $1-\cos x\ge 0$. Also $x\ge 0$ so $f\ge 0$.

Comment: yes but is`nt it suppose to be >?

Comment: Well.. this is because not only your function is $\ge 0$ but it is continuous and positive on some interval, say on $[\pi/8,\pi/4]$.